# What is Isolation in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, transaction-isolation

I'm not understanding the concept of *isolation*, in `hibernate`. Can anyone explain it, and present some possible usage cases?

Comment: Are you referring to IsolationLevel?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Answer (score 1):

Isolation in hibernate is similar to transactional isolations provided by database i.e the degree to which the data being updated is visible to other transaction taking place concurrently.Every database provide default isolation settings. There are [isolation-levels](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/devguide/cdevconcepts15366.html). And hibernate provides you to set the isolation level for your application. Refer [hibernate-doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) for it

Answer (score 0):

Taking for example MS Sql Server the isolation level describes the read strategy from the tables, that is telling the server if it should read uncommitted transactions, only committed ones, snapshot a.s.o. The settings vary depending on the type of sql used.

[SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL - MS SQL SERVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)